# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS upgrade regarding

Tags: updates, update-manager, 18.04

I use "Software Updater" to get new updates.

For "Ubuntu Software", the "Download from" is set to "Main server" and for "Updates", the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" is set as "For any new version"

In spite of the above, I did not get any notification 18.04 LTS new version

Should I have to wait for notification or should do a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028949/why-i-am-not-getting-ubuntu-18-04-upgrade]?

Answer (score 2):

**Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or 17.10**

Upgrades from 17.10 will not be enabled until a few days after 18.04's release (April 26, 2018).

Upgrades from 16.04 LTS will not be enabled until a few days after the 18.04.1 release expected in late July.

There are no offline upgrade options for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server.

This is from here: [wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes](https:////wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below command which will upgrade your system to the latest ubuntu

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

If it shows that there is no new upgrades you could set the `-d` flag for development version, which is almost same and with very to no bugs as the new release is out already

`sudo do-release-upgrade -d`