# I can't upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 from 17.10

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, development, release-management, 18.04

I have tried using `do-release-upgrade`. It shows

```
no release found
```

I tried using `do-release-upgrade -d`. It says

```
development releases can only be upgraded from LTS releases
```

I tried `sudo update-manager -c`, and it shows an error something like

```
MIT-MAGIC COOKIE refused connection
```

What do I do?

Comment: Your question is already asked and answered [Why I am not getting ubuntu 18.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/q/1028949/29012).

Answer (score 5):

> **Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or 17.10**
>   Upgrades from 17.10 will not be enabled until a few days after 18.04's release. Upgrades from 16.04 LTS will not be enabled until a few days after the 18.04.1 release expected in late July.
>
> There are no offline upgrade options for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server.

That's the official announcement from [Bionic Beaver release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I am not an expert but after reading various posts I tried these commands and finally got my system to start the update:

xhost +

sudo xhost si:localuser:root

sudo update-manager -cd

This problem is related to Wayland. Maybe an expert can explain.

Hope this works for you...I know this can be frustrating :-)

Comment: very strange, but worked also for me, on Ubuntu Mate 17.10. Thank you!