# Problems with upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

After dist-upgrade my system on 16.04 I've received such problems - some gui's don't appear correctly, can't install new packages and after command `apt-get -f install` received such printing

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 appmenu-qt5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 checkbox-converged : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin but it is not installable
 evolution-data-server : Depends: evolution-data-server-common (= 3.18.5-1ubuntu1) but 3.28.1-1ubuntu1 is installed
 gnome-calendar : Depends: gsettings-desktop-schemas (>= 3.21.2) but 3.18.1-1ubuntu1 is installed
 gnome-shell : Depends: libgjs0-libmozjs-24-0 but it is not installable
               Depends: libgjs0e (>= 1.44.0) but it is not installable
               Recommends: gnome-themes-standard-data but it is not installed
 hplip : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.24) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6-amd64:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (= 2.23-0ubuntu10) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu10) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu10) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu10) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.48.2-0ubuntu1) but 2.56.1-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.48.2-0ubuntu1) but 2.56.1-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libglvnd-dev : Depends: libegl1 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2) but it is not installed
 libgoa-1.0-0b : Depends: libgoa-1.0-common (= 3.18.3-1ubuntu2) but 3.28.0-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libgoa-backend-1.0-1 : Depends: libgoa-1.0-0b (>= 3.25.4) but 3.18.3-1ubuntu2 is installed
 libkf5declarative5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 liboxideqtcore0 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt53dcore5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt53dinput5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt53dquick5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
                  Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 but it is not installable
 libqt53dquickrenderer5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt53drenderer5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5contacts5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5core5a : Depends: libdouble-conversion1 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not installed
 libqt5designer5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5location5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5multimedia5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5opengl5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed
 libqt5organizer5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5positioning5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5printsupport5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.6.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed
 libqt5quicktest5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed
 libqt5quickwidgets5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.6.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed
 libqt5script5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5sensors5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5sql5-sqlite : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5svg5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5waylandclient5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5webkit5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
                 Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 but it is not installable
 libqt5websockets5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libqt5widgets5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed
 libqt5xmlpatterns5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libubuntutoolkit5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 libunity-webapps0 : Depends: unity-webapps-service but it is not installable
 libwayland-egl1-mesa : Depends: libegl1 but it is not installed
 onboard : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 pay-ui : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin but it is not installable
 python3-brlapi : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-cairo : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-cffi-backend : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-cryptography : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-cups : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-dbus : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-dbus.mainloop.qt : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.5.1-3) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-evdev : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-gdbm : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-gi : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-gi-cairo : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-libapparmor : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-lxml : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-markupsafe : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-pil : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-psutil : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-pycurl : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-pyqt4 : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-renderpm : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-reportlab-accel : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-scipy : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-simplejson : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-sip : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-systemd : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-uno : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 python3-yaml : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 qml-module-qtlocation : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
                         Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 but it is not installable
 qml-module-qtpositioning : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 but it is not installable
 qml-module-qtquick-controls : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed
 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed
 qml-module-qtquick-layouts : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
                              Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 but it is not installable
 qml-module-qtquick-localstorage : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 but it is not installable
 qml-module-qtquick-particles2 : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 but it is not installable
 qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
                                     Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 but it is not installable
 qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 qml-module-qtquick2 : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 but it is not installable
 qml-module-qttest : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 but it is not installable
 qml-module-ubuntu-test : Depends: qml-module-ubuntu-components but it is not installable
                          Depends: libubuntugestures5 but it is not installable
                          Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 qml-module-ubuntu-web : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin (>= 1.3) but it is not installable or
                                  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin-gles (>= 1.3) but it is not installable
 qmlscene : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 qtbase5-dev : Depends: libqt5gui5 (= 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 is installed
 qtdeclarative5-dev-tools : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 but it is not installable
 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-push-plugin : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin but it is not installable
 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-telephony-phonenumber0.1 : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin but it is not installable
 qtwayland5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 but it is not installable
 rhythmbox : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 software-properties-gtk : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.96.20.7) but 0.96.24.32.1 is installed
 totem-plugins : Depends: python3 (< 3.6) but 3.6.5-3 is installed
 ubuntu-keyboard-data : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin but it is not installable
 unity-control-center : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-17 (>= 3.27.90) but it is not installed
                        Recommends: system-config-printer but it is not installed
                        Recommends: gnome-control-center-faces but it is not installed
 unity-webapps-qml : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin but it is not installable or
                              qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin-gles but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

How could I repair such issues?

Comment: 18.04 is not ready for upgrading 16.04 in place. That comes after the first point release, 18.04.1, which comes in June.

Comment: This is a great question that calls for an authoritative reference answer.

Comment: This is too late to help you but everyone reading should consider upgrading 16.04 to 18.04 in a test environment (cloned partition) first. You can manually do this booting with a Live USB or use this automated script without booting a Live USB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade/1028605#1028605

Answer (score 1):

1. After upgrading you **must** reboot.
2. Make sure you sign-on selecting Unity from the drop down gear menu:

   [image: Ubuntu 18.04 Five Desktops.jpg]
3. After signing in the first thing you **must** do is open a terminal and run:

   `sudo apt update`

   `sudo apt upgrade`