# Unable to upgrade 16.04 to Bionic Beaver 18.04?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

I'm using 16.04. I ran `apt update`, `apt upgrade`, `apt dist-upgrade`, followed by `do-release-upgrade`.

I get this message:

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release
>   No new release found.

I run `lsb_release -a`, and I'm still using 16.04.

Why is it not upgrading?

Comment: This kind of question keeps coming up, and soon we'll have a good reference Q&A to explain that 18.04 LTS will not be ready to perform this kind of upgrade until the first point release 18.04.1

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_or_17.10

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` but I highly recommend doing this on a test partition with a clone of your 16.04 system. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade/1028605#1028605

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [the "Upgrading from LTS" section](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_16.04_LTS) of the Release Notes,

> Upgrades from 16.04 LTS will not be enabled until a few days after 18.04.1's release, expected in [late July.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule)

The idea behind this is that people who upgrade from one long term stable (LTS)  release to another will most likely appreciate the improved stability of 18.04.1.

Comment: Looks like this happened https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2018-July/000234.html Yet `No new release found`

Comment: @endolith I have (anecdotally) discovered that the new release is not available until [this changelog page](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts) updates. At least for 16.04 and 14.04. As Wilbert's quote says, it takes "a few days" after release for the `dist-upgrade` to be listed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` prior to July 26, 2018 and drop the `-d` after that.

I highly recommend doing this on a test partition with a clone of your 16.04 system. See: [Bash script to clone Ubuntu to new partition for testing 18.04 LTS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade/1028605#1028605)

Answer (score 0):

sudo do-release-upgrade -d 
will upgrade to the last release candidate.  The final release is not in the repository yet.  You might have to first upgrade to series 17 to get there.