# ubuntu Does not start After updating to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, 18.04

Due to some reason the system update stop &then after ubuntu won't start ......
It was fully downloaded but not fully install.

Comment: Would you kindly elaborate the "updating to 18.04" from which version, and the process you followed?

Comment: It's too late to help you now. But for other users please consider testing the 18.04 Update on a cloned partition first. See this script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade/1028605#1028605