# Ubuntu 18.04 "unable to connect to scanner"

Tags: hp, scanner, 18.04

I have an HP MFP M225dn multipurpose printer-scanner. In my new install of 18.04, printing works fine, simple scan recognizes the scanner but won't scan ("unable to connect to scanner"). Was working fine with 16.04 and the HP print manager (HPLIP) software.
Anyone else seeing this? Should I install the HPLIP drivers etc. from HP? They do not list 18.04 compatibility.
Cheers

p.s. Sane detects the scanner:

```
xxxxxx@daniel-Z370N:~$ sudo sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [Hewlett-Packard], product=0x2d2a [HP LaserJet Pro MFP M225dn]) at libusb:001:014
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

xxxxx@daniel-Z370N:~$ sudo scanimage -L

device `hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M225dn?serial=CNB9HBWD3M' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M225dn all-in-one

xxxxx@daniel-Z370N:~$
```

Comment: When I tested 16.04 to 18.04 upgrade I noticed a new `sane` configuration file could be installed. I chose "Y" to update it did you do the same?

Comment: You can clone your 16.04 to a new partition and update it to 18.04 as well without impacting your live data. Then you can test if that works. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa or: https://thelinuxcode.com/clone-hard-drive-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/

Comment: Hmmm. I did a fresh install of 18.04 on a new motherboard and drive... so lots of variables I guess...

Comment: But you use 16.04 day to day for your livelihood or hobby. One day you'll want to upgrade it to 18.04. Which was my comment about testing the 16.04 to 18.04 upgrade and using it before doing it for real. Upgrading is more complicated than fresh install and subject to many more errors. In my situation I have 500 GB SSD and 1000 GB HDD. Ubuntu was only 44 GB partition (37% full), so I created a 25 GB partition for the 16.04 clone which I've upgraded to 18.04 for testing.  From many years of personal experience testing is well worth the time. I'll test my Brother Printer/Scanner soon in 18.04.

Comment: OK, I'll follow your suggestion tomorrow on the old hardware... you are right about testing before jumping in! Thanks!

Comment: Thank-you NOrbert. I installed hplip and it is now scanning perfectly.

Comment: Same issue here with Samsung SCX-3205W. Over Wi-Fi the printer prints, the scanner is not found. The scanner used to work in 16.04.