# Problem upgrading Kubuntu 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 18.04

Today I decided to upgrade Kubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 following Kubuntu's official site steps https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BionicUpgrades/Kubuntu. Although I updated the system, the option to upgrade didn't appear in Discover, so following the site's instructions did this: `kdesudo "do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE"`.
Everything okay until I reboot... Instead of Kubuntu 18.04 now I have Ubuntu 18.04??!

Does anybody know why this happened?

---

Edit: I tried changing the desktop environment to Kubuntu using `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` but it doesn't recognize the command

Comment: I had the same (or similar problem), but in my case I had an error that `kubuntu-desktop` can't be installed and after the upgrade ended with an error I sucessfully run `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` and `apt --fix-broken-install` and still I was getting into the Ubuntu (Gnome I guess) login screen to which I couldn't even login. In other alt-x terminals I could login and rerun all upgrade and fix commands, and it seemed it was stable, but the KDE would not load.

Answer (score 1):

"Upgrades from 16.04 LTS will not be enabled until a few days after the 18.04.1 release expected in late July."

I think the option is not enabled yet

Comment: But that's for the 16.04 LTS and I have (had) 17.10

Comment: 16.04 Users can upgrade before 18.04.1 LTS by using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. Of course they should do this on a clone of 16.04 first and not live installation: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I Followed the steps in the release notes and it worked for me.

The upgrade should run uninterrupted. You will need to:

1. If you have a laptop make sure it is connected to power.
2. If at all practical, ensure that you are connected to the Internet
   via a wired connection.
3. Ensure your current installation is updated using **Plasma Discover**
4. Run the release upgrade tool.
5. Reboot.

**Upgrade**

If for some reason **Discover** does not offer you the upgrade to 18.04, then you can open Krunner, or Konsole (or other terminal), and run:

```
kdesudo "do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE"
```

- Allow the upgrade to start, wait (approximately an hour).
- Remove obsolete packages when asked
- It will ask you to restart your computer. Ensure you have no unsaved work open and click **Restart Now**.

source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BionicUpgrades/Kubuntu

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "doesn't recognize the command"?

If your Ubuntu 18.04 is working normally and you want to go back to KDE:

```
~$ sudo apt-get update
~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
~$ sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

(if it says it's already installed, ignore it and go to next command, if it shows some error, post them here)

```
~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
```

Make sure to select sddm from list and Ok.
Now reboot and Plasma should be loaded.

Now continue from KDE Terminal:

```
~$ sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop
~$ sudo apt-get purge nautilus
~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
~$ sudo apt-get autoclean
```