# How to upgrade or install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from ISO file without any USB or DVD?

Tags: 18.04

I downloaded the latest LTS release of Ubuntu 18.04. I currently do not have any spare USB or CD/DVD. So, I just want to install or upgrade my current system from that ISO without making any bootable device. Is it possible? If yes, then please tell me the whole process!

Comment: Your solution requires knowledge of your system. If you have a spare HDD in it, you can `dd` the iso to the hdd/sdd so as to use it in place of a usb/dvd (not install drive though). If you don't want to use the whole drive, you can use a partition on a drive (*ie. part of a hdd/sdd*). If you already have grub, you can add entries to your existing grub to boot the ISO, then select the 'iso' and install from there (*this requires the least work & fix-up afterwards*).  I'd still recommend using a usb/dvd (back one up somewhere, use it, then restore data to it, or just go to a store & buy another)

Comment: You can install to the same drive you boot the Live installer system from, as long as you boot toram. I will try to write up a procedure later today.

Comment: You could boot the ISO with grub using loopback feature. I'll an answer later

Comment: It is risky to upgrade, so you should backup and/or create a test system before you do it on your main operating system. See this link, which creates a system, that you can use for testing alongside your main system, [Bash script to clone Ubuntu to new partition for testing 18.04 LTS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade)

Comment: I usually do an upgrade using Software and Updates for LTS versions. This is simple, preserves /home and updates the installed programs. I've had good luck with this method. and you don't need an external drive, or an ISO. Some people prefer a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

**Backup! everything will be overwritten.**

Copy Ubuntu 18.04 ISO to HDD root, (/).

Edit grub.cfg changing 40_custom as shown:

```
    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
    # This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
    # menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
    # the 'exec tail' line above.
        menuentry "ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64" {
            loopback loop (hd0,2)/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso
            linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso splash toram -- 
            initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
    }
    ### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
```

Install Ubuntu as normal, but you only get one chance.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote? (hd0,2) may need to be modified depending on where "/" is.

Comment: If there is a spare partition it might be worthwhile to use it for /home

Answer (score 0):

So using the **loopback** feature of **GRUB**, one can boot an **iso** installed on a partition of you HDD.

1. Copy the ubuntu ISO to one spare partition. By spare, I mean, one partition that you will not overwrite when installing ubuntu. For example, your NTFS windows partition.
2. Add an entry in grub configuration for the iso. To do that edit `/etc/grub/40_custom` and add something like

   ```
   insmod search_fs_uuid
   insmod ntfs
   search --no-floppy --set=isopart --fs-uuid XXXXXXXXXXXXX

   menuentry '[loopback]ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64' {
       set isofile='/Grub/ISO/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
       loopback loop ($isopart)$isofile
       linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile locale=en_US.UTF-8
       initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
   }
   ```

   This needs a little explanation

   This will search for your partition by filesystem **uuid**. So you need to know the uuid of your fs partition. You can use the output of `blkid` for that. Look for **UUID** not PARTUUID. So replace XXXXXXXXXX with the uuid of your fs.

   If your partition is not NTFS then you need to insmod the module for your fs like ext4.

   The `isofile` variable is relative to the **root** of your partition, not the root of your current system.
   For example I have `/media/me/Windows10/Grub/ISO/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso`, as the ISO, so I use `/Grub/ISO/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso` as the isofile
3. Run `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot and, in Grub menu, choose the loopback entry.
   Then do the installation as if booted from USB or DVD.

Comment: What if you do not have a spare partition? Even with a spare partition, if something goes wrong with the install the old install including grub will be gone the same as with my answer.

Comment: But if I make a separate partition, my data will get effected!

Comment: You can resize a partition without affecting data in the alongside partition. Use a gparted Live UB