# Upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 crashes when extracting bionic

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 18.04, crash

**Hi everyone,**

So over the past month I've tried many times to upgrade from `Ubuntu 17.10` to `18.04`. Every time I try to do an update it crashes, it always crashes on the line `extracting bionic.tar.gz`.

I've tried the following things:

- Updating from the command line.
- Updating with the GUI.

I've tried many other small things like repairing broken packages and removing and reinstalling them.

Google doesn't seem to be able to help me so I **hope** someone else can help me!

**Thanks in advance.**

PS:

If I update from the GUI the bionic window stays black and after 5-10 minutes the whole system freezes.

Comment: I hope you've made a backup of 17.10 or have cloned it and are testing upgrade on a test partition.

Comment: My system works fine as always but it just doesn't upgrade. I've made backups but if I can't even upgrade there is no point on even having backups. @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: Something could go wrong and neither 17.10 nor 18.04 works leaving you with an expensive paper weight. See https://askubuntu.com/q/1028604/307523