# rsync symlink failed: Operation not permitted (1)

Tags: command-line, backup, rsync

When I run either of these commands, I get the error `rsync symlink failed: Operation not permitted (1)`:

```
sudo rsync -aAXv --delete --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/tmp/* \ 
--exclude=/run/* --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/media/* --exclude="swapfile" --exclude="lost+found" \ 
--exclude=".cache" --exclude="Downloads" --exclude=".VirtualBoxVMs" --exclude=".ecryptfs" /source \ 
/destination
```

or

```
sudo rsync -rltzuv --delete --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/tmp/* \ 
--exclude=/run/* --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/media/* --exclude="swapfile" --exclude="lost+found" \ 
--exclude=".cache" --exclude="Downloads" --exclude=".VirtualBoxVMs" --exclude=".ecryptfs" / \ 
/media/hanif/CEDF-4BFB/Backup
```

Neither of these work.  They both show the same error:

```
rsync symlink failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

[image: console]

**Can anybody help me to get this backing up properly?**

Comment: Try the `-K` option see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116775/how-to-copy-directory-structure-without-removing-symlinks

Comment: You can create a shorter command by putting all the excludes together. For example this Answer (**that works**): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade/1028605#1028605 uses: `rsync -haxAX --stats --delete --info=progress2 --info=name0 /* "$TargetMnt"  --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found}`

Comment: the error is because symlinks get ignored without the -K option being used. also, instead of posting screen-shot, copy and paste your command line output into your question

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting). This seems like a permission problem to me, `rsync` is not permitted to create symlinks under `/media/hanif/CEDF-4BFB/Backup/`. Please [edit] and provide the output of `stat /media/hanif/CEDF-4BFB/Backup/`.

Answer (score 2):

As you used the option `-l` or `--links` preserving symlinks, I suspect that you tried to copy symlinks to a FAT partition, which does not support symlinks, independently of rsync.