# Directly selecting text on hyperlinks? (In Windows with Alternate+Drag cursor, no drag/drop)

Tags: keyboard, mouse, browser, text

In Windows, if I hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and select text by clicking and dragging, it works.

In Linux, it moves the window of the browser like any other window.

Selecting a hyperlink and dragging it usually does drag the whole link for **drag-and-dropping.**

How can I easily select text on a hyperlink like I can in Windows?

Comment: What Ubuntu version (flavour) do you use? I actually wasn't aware of that `Alt+Mouse` thing and always suffered from not being able to just select a link's text instead of dragging the whole thing. (Thank you for that!) Now I tried with `Alt+mouse` and it works for me. I'm on U17.10.

Comment: @PerlDuck U17.10--Shockingly is EOL :p

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, I didn't yet dare to update. But it's on my TODO list for the next couple of days. Currently I need my PC to operate and cannot risk anything.

Comment: @PerlDuck I totally understand. The U18.04 bug reports are scary. Make sure you clone your 17.10 and upgrade it and test it thoroughly before doing it for real. Check my script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade

Comment: @PerlDuck What about an ESR?

Comment: @PerlDuck At the moment: Linux Mint 18.3 MATE. (technically very similar to Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually position my mouse cursor to the left or right of they hyper-link. Then <kbd>Left-Click</kbd> and drag the cursor over the hyper-link.

If you only want a portion in the middle of the of the hyper-link, then you must use <kbd>winKey</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Click</kbd> and drag your mouse over the portion you want.