# Brave browser not starting due to snap mount namespace error

Tags: chromium, snap, apparmor

Brave installed from snap was running perfectly fine for months.
Since two days it is not starting when clicking Brave icon from launcher.
When attempting to run Brave from command line just calling `brave` I am getting following warnings, browser starts but without all my profile data (bookmarks, configuration, history), and it is in unsafe --no-sandbox modee.

```
main.go:224: cannot change mount namespace of snap "brave" according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/818/share/icons/Suru /snap/brave/44/data-dir/icons/Suru none bind,ro 0 0): cannot use "/snap/gtk-common-themes/818/share/icons/Suru" as bind-mount source: not a directory
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient;
```

It looks like snap-AppArmor integration issue.

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

`snap version`

```
snap    2.36.2
snapd   2.36.2
series  16
ubuntu  18.04
kernel  4.15.0-42-generic
```

`apt policy apparmor`

```
apparmor:
  Installed: 2.12-4ubuntu5.1
```

`snap info brave`

```
name:      brave
summary:   A browser with your interests at heart.
publisher: Brave Software (brave*)
contact:   https://community.brave.com/
license:   unset
description: |
  Browse faster by blocking ads and trackers that violate your privacy and
  cost you time and money.
commands:
  - brave
snap-id:      uE3hSmGE91m9MpbDEnUWi2vpeumH6gmv
tracking:     stable
refresh-date: today at 10:26 IST
channels:                              
  stable:    v0.56.12-5.dev (44) 160MB -
  candidate: ^                         
  beta:      ^                         
  edge:      ^                         
installed:   v0.56.12-5.dev (44) 160MB -
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution presented [here](https://dev.getsol.us/T6899) is to use:

```
sudo usysconf run -f
```

Additionally in the link another user points out you don't need to use `snap` because `brave` is in the repo's now. You can download the `brave` `.deb` installation package [here](https://community.brave.com/t/how-do-i-install-brave-in-ubuntu/7901/11).

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about recommended way? installing Brave from `.deb`? Uninstalling snap one before? how to ensure my profile from snap will work on repo's Brave? any special procedure to migrate? my snap brave is still 0.25

Comment: Well first things first, did you try the `sudo usysconf run -f` command? As far as converting from a `snap` to a traditional `.deb` installed with `dpkg -i` that will take some research.

Comment: Unfortunately no, after having no access to my browser's profile for weeks I am afraid to try anything that is not a complete and official recipe. I cannot afford that.

Comment: @jangorecki If you have enough disk space, you can create a new partition and then clone your current partition to it. Then run `usyconf` command on the clone and see if it works ok. See: [Bash script to clone Ubuntu to new partition for testing 18.04 LTS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade/1028605#1028605)

Comment: creating partition and cloning partition? I opened question on community forum, hopefully there is easier way. https://community.brave.com/t/migrate-profile-from-snap-brave-to-repo-brave/42879

Answer (score 2):

The answer in the second section is obsolete because the Brave snap package has been discontinued. The current instructions for installing Brave browser in Ubuntu from the official Brave browser website are as follows. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl
curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brave-browser
```

Comment: Thanks for trying help. I don't use Firefox. I use Brave, all my bookmarks are there but I cannot access them if I will start `snap run brave` or `brave`. It starts brave but in `--no-sandbox` mode, not in using my profile. Brave browser does not start by clicking on its icon in Dash even after starting it once from console.

Comment: Brave browser will open normally by clicking on its icon in the Dash after you have entered your new settings in the Brave welcome tour screens and saved the changed settings.

Comment: I need to use my existing settings rather creating new ones

Comment: I do not have anything to import from Firefox, all I have is already in Brave, but the profile that I cannot access

Answer (score 2):

Not a real solution but at least it allows me to access my profile data in Brave.

```
sudo snap revert brave
```

Now Brave starts normally.