# Upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS to 16.03.6 safe or not?

Tags: 14.04, server, upgrade

So I'm in the process of upgrading my "SERVER" not desktop...
There are 320 packages that can be updated
I've installed systemback and created a restore point I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.4.4 LTS and I want to upgrade to 16.4.6 LTS my server has a lot of stuff on it, multiple websites, data etc... and if something fails such as causing down time i'm screwed.

I can't seem to find the "safest" solution for updating my Ubuntu server or should updating my ubuntu server not have any impact on my live data/sites..?

1. is it safe to upgrade from 14.04.4 LTS to 16.04.6 LTS (i've taken a backup of the server)
2. If anything goes wrong, can I use my restore point that I took in my 14.4 LTS (before upgrading) and revert back to 14.4 LTS after I have already installed 16.4 LTS?

or if you have any other suggestions I'd be happy to hear them.

Thank you!
-Paul

Comment: This might be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade

Comment: 1. Upgrades have been safe for me, but IMHO, it would be wise to test an upgrade first. 2. Yes, why else would make a snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would just make a Clonezilla backup image of your system drive.  You could then upgrade, and if it breaks something, just restore the image and it'll be like nothing ever happened.  That way you don't have to worry about the restore point not working post-upgrade.