# Unity's window size/position shortcuts on Gnome

Tags: unity, gnome, 19.04, shortcuts, tweak

I love and I'm so used to the ALT+Mouse to move a window and SHIFT+Mouse to resize evenly shortcuts that Unity has, but now I'm thinking on moving to Gnome and I am not able to find those gestures in there.

Is there a way to add them to Gnome?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are thinking of moving of moving from Unity to Gnome there are more significant changes to worry about. Out of curiosity what are the features of Gnome you covet?

Comment: There's no specific feature at all, I just like more how default Gnome looks and feels. I know that I can customize Unity with themes, but currently I'm feeling more comfortable on Gnome.

Comment: Oh well in that case I've upgraded 16.04 unity to 18.04 gnome many times and played with it. You can do it too in a painless fashion: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-backkup-clone-ubuntu-to-another-partition/1028605#1028605 It's just after using it for a few weeks I just fall back to the original is all.

Comment: I think that we are not in the same channel. I don't plan to copy any data/programs to anywhere. I'm already on a Gnome fresh install and I just want to know if there is a way to add the above shortcuts that default ubuntu-unity-desktop has.

The ALT+Mouse to move a window without going all the way up to the toolbar and SHIFT+Mouse to resize a window on both sides evenly.

Comment: The "ALT+Mouse" feature is present in GNOME. I don't remember correctly, but it might be SUPER instead of ALT by default. In that case it can be changed to ALT easily. Not sure about the"SHIFT+Mouse" feature though.

Comment: You're right. Gnome uses Super instead of Alt, and it can be easily "reverted" using Gnome Tweaks. Still can't find SHIFT+Mouse, tho. Thank you so much!