# How to backup the whole desktop — without backing up junk?

Tags: backup, rsync

I'm looking to take a whole system backup and store it on S3. Something that could be good enough to restore my entire system. But I've been told that using dd/rsync to capture the root directory will save a lot of extraneous files that I wouldn't need to restore the system.

In the event that I had to reply on this backup, I would need to restore:

- The home directory
- All installed programs
- All customizations throughout the system, such as edits to the Openbox configuration file, etc

The command I see recommended [here](https://www.ostechnix.com/backup-entire-linux-system-using-rsync/) is:

```
sudo rsync -aAXv / --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /mnt
```

Is it possible to go lighter than that?

Comment: This won't save boot loaders and so forth, so restoring from it will include installing those manually. What software do you have installed? For me, reinstalling takes ~1hr, as I have a fair Idea of what software I need. I only care about backing up ~. The rest is trivially restorable.

Comment: Do you really need "all installed programs", or is it okay to download them later based on current package configuration?  I.e. would saving /usr/local, /home, and /etc be sufficient?

Answer (score 4):

You might look at a combination of `Backups` (Déjà Dup) for your /home, and `Timeshift` for the system stuff. Otherwise, use `Macrium Reflect` to clone your entire disk/partition.

The closest thing to a Windows-like restore point is by using `Timeshift`. I use it to save snapshots to an external USB hard drive. Although it can, it's normally not used for backing up your /home directory, just system-level changes. Use `Backups` (Déjà Dup) for backing up /home files.

```
Timeshift is a system restore utility which takes snapshots
of the system at regular intervals. These snapshots can be restored
at a later date to undo system changes. Creates incremental snapshots
using rsync or BTRFS snapshots using BTRFS tools.
```

More information at https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift

For pre-19.04 users, add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
```

And install with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install timeshift
```

Comment: An edit *and an upvote!*  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks! I'm already using Timeshift in combination with Clonezilla. The former, as you say, to roll back to a snapshot (in the event that is required). The latter to save my system if stuff really goes belly up (although I learned recently that you can use Timeshift as a CLI, which would have saved me reinstalling my last system the last time I had to when I couldn't get passed GRUB).

Comment: @DanielR keep in mind that Clonezilla won't clone to a smaller disk than the source. This means that you probably won't be able to restore from a clone backup.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Bash script to backkup/clone Ubuntu to another partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-backkup-clone-ubuntu-to-another-partition/1028605#1028605)

```
rsync -haxAX --stats --delete --info=progress2 --info=name0 --inplace  \
      /* "$TargetMnt"                                                   \
      --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found}
```

The script also updates `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `/etc/fstab` so you can boot your backup.