# Jack audio volume issue

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.04 (upgraded from 18.04.3) and I've been testing the Jack Audio System.

Even the fact that I've got sounds from all the software I use (Audacity, MuseScore, Firefox and Wine) and all the internal (the PC internal audio card) and external audio device (a Behringer Analog Audio Mixer through USB interface)... I cannot to control the Jack overall audio volume!

I mean: I put all the PAVU controls to zero dB (100%), but... It is too much to the external USB mixer! The final audio from Jack is around 10 dB above the standard zero value!

It is worst if I used the Calf audio effects!

I cannot to find some specific Jack volume control.

If I close the Jack server, then the audio volume back to the "right" amount of audio.

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158652/is-there-a-way-to-control-the-jack-output-volume-via-terminal-or-get-a-pulseaudi