# Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 upgrade failed

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

I've been regularly keeping my 16.04 up to date with the software updater. When I tried to upgrade to 18.04, it took a long time, then at the very end popped up a box saying it failed (bad enough in itself), but also my machine might (!) be in an unusable state. I should have *screenshotted* it; I was only given the option of clicking OK or something, so I'm not sure of the wording. I seem to be running for now, but I'm afraid to reboot.

Comment: If you want your release-upgrade to be perfect/flawless, you need to remove unofficial sources & packages (they may have version numbers that prevent release-upgrade from working as intended as 3rd parties are free to ignore Ubuntu standards) then release-upgrade, then add back the unofficial sources if you still need them. You will see the message again if you look in logs, but in your place I would reboot (you already have your backups) & login only to terminal,  confirm what is running (is it 16.04?, 18.04? or in-between?) and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to attempt to complete upgrade process.

Comment: .. I would take note of any messages, and adjust accordingly, but the aim would be to get `dist-upgrade` to complete (assuming you've booted into a full/part 18.04 system).  I'd probably also inspect your sources (look for where problems are likely to be created by, and what may be needed to fix), but once I had got `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` to complete without issues, then I'd reboot again & expect a 18.04 system.  Only then would I attempt gui login.  If this is a message, install from thumb-drive using 'something-else' & **no-format**  so you don't need those backups.

Comment: I've removed the '*rant*' part of your question (it's off-topic - see https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) and your whole question may have been closed because of it.   *You could also wait for other opinions; I've only told you what I would do in your position; and I was brief as had no desire to go into more depth due to rant*

Comment: Next time you can create a new partition and [Clone 16.04 to new partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-backkup-clone-ubuntu-to-another-partition/1028605#1028605) and perform upgrade (or anything experimental) on the clone first.

Comment: Well, you must reboot sometime. Prepare wisely: Choose your time, make yourself a LiveUSB installer, backup your data, then reboot.