# How to backup current state? For recovery AND migration?

Tags: backup

I use some widgets and now will install some apps. Want to have clean system after i mess it up, or to save a current clean installation backup for new install. Also after web browsers set up to migrate with extensions installed. Extension migration on Chrome for example dont migrate.

Comment: I think this link can help you :
https://superuser.com/a/990619

Comment: Before you 'mess things up', open Disks (gnome-disks) and highlight the root partition. Click on the little gear icon, and you will see an option to create an image. You will need  to decide which device to back up the image to, and its path. Then after selecting this go ahead and create the image.

Comment: The fastest and easiest way of doing this sort of tasks is to use `btrfs` filesystem and use snapshots.

Comment: "Also after web browsers set up to migrate with extensions installed. " ehm browsers use "synch"  for that(?)

Comment: For thouse who dont have synced chrome and firefox. Just now tried to make profile copy, but extensions are lost since some encryption is going on.

Comment: You can clone ubuntu to other partitions that will appear in grub menu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-backkup-clone-ubuntu-to-another-partition/1028605#1028605