# Unable to boot Ubuntu cloned from USB to SSD using Clonezilla

Tags: boot, 16.04, usb, ssd, clonezilla

I'm trying to clone Ubuntu 16.04 from USB stick (Sandisk 128GB installed with Ubuntu 16.04 - /sdc) to external SSD (brand new WD SN550 250GB - /sdd) on my Windows machine.

Following [this tutorial](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone), I made a Clonezilla USB then boot to it, connect my Ubuntu USB (Sandisk - /sdc) and external SSD (WD - /sdd), choose source and target as Sandisk and WD respectively, then finish the clone.  Then remove Ubuntu USB (Sandisk) and Clonezilla USB, then reboot. Until now, my BIOS setup is EFI.

But when I reboot, my WD SSD doesn't show up when I press F12. Also there're something different running in the background during cloning. Here're some screenshots, saying `the boot loader on /dev/xxx is not grub skip running grub-install` and some other strange stuff.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

How do I fix it to boot to Ubuntu SSD? Should I have done something to the WD SSD prior of cloning?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are attempting to clone *from*?  Ubuntu was *installed* on your flash drive? (Not an ISO image)?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 16.04 was installed on the Sandisk USB, and I'm cloning it to WD SSD using Clonezilla.

Comment: After cloning you need to set UUID in grub and /etc/fstab. For example see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-backkup-clone-ubuntu-to-another-partition/1028605#1028605

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don’t see grub after cloning. The SSD doesn’t show up at boot to choose from.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Actually the UUID are the same for all the partitions in my SSD as the source Ubuntu USB, I just checked them in disk utility.